# Table with least repeated values grouped

Tags: r

I have a very large data frame and want to create some simple tables. The problem with a dataset so big, is that I have a lot of values that only occur a few times.

What I want to achieve is to create a table for each of the qualitative variables, and have the least occuring values in each variable appear under a grouped tag. The first part is easy enough:

```
 sapply(dat[!sapply(dat, is.numeric)], table)
```

but how do I group the values that are present less than x times and also put them in the table in a 'Others' tag? Is there any table function that has a parameter that does this? Or am I going to have to manually manipulate the `data.frame`, find all the lest occuring values and change the value for them to 'Other'?

Comment: You're going to need to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for this, as it is too vague at the moment. Whether you use a portion of your actual data or a standard data as an example is up to you, but please find something and edit your question.

Comment: See `fct_lump` from the `forcats` package. It automates grouping infrequent categories into a single "other" group.

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for eipi10. Thanks